# Minecraft crashing on startup in Ubuntu

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux, ubuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 instead of Windows for various reasons and I installed Minecraft.
When I open it and run version 1.8.9 it crashes almost instantly.
This is the error I get when launching the game:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:807)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:886)
    at org.lwjgl.LinuxSysImplementation.(LinuxSysImplementation.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.createImplementation(Sys.java:131)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.(Sys.java:116)
    at ave.J(SourceFile:2539)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:41)
```

Comment: DId you actually install Minecraft or do you get this message *when* installing?

Comment: Which java version are you using? I tend to have issues running older minecraft with anything but java 8.

Answer (score 1):

- Searching for (the first two lines of) the error led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260989) on StackOverflow, saying

  > "*one of the more common causes of this exception is a **missing or corrupt installation of a [Java Access Bridge](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-tech-access-bridge.html)**.*"

  The accepted answer also mentions to follow the instructions for installing [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/setup.htm).
- Alternatively, it could be indicative of a "headless Java installation".
  One of the comments in [this bugthread](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-9795) mentions that

  > "*We should make it clear in the description of the tarball install on minecraft.net that **non-headless java is needed** (`openjdk-8-jre`).*"